# check_box_tag checked state for the first element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form_tag in which I display a table, one column of that table it has a `check_box_tag`

```
<%@competitors.each do |competitor|%>
  <td><%= check_box_tag "competitor_ids[]", competitor.id%></td>
<%end%>
```

Is it possible to tick just the first `competitor` and submit the form and how?

Comment: but how, I tried sending the id of the first competitor, and then compare with the value which is stored in the `input value`, but I think there should be a easier way.

Comment: Can you maybe share that code then, so we better understand what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` as follows to `check` the checkbox at `zero` index:

```
<% @competitors.each_with_index do |competitor, index| %>
  <td><%= check_box_tag "competitor_ids[]", competitor.id, index.zero? %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Alex, My bad, please see updated answer.  I've removed invalid `checked` key, so instead of `checked: index.zero?`, use `index.zero?` in third parameter.

Comment: My bad for not checking the documentation, but it worked now. Thank you